# How do I return the value of the TextArea to the ActionResult after it has been edited

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm pretty new to MVC but have managed to return values from the view to the controller using this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExtendBookingForwardsInTime", "Listings", new { bookingID = Model.BookingID }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ExtendBookingForwardsInTime" }))
      {
           <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('ExtendBookingForwardsInTime').submit();">Extend Forwards</a>
      }
```

However, this just returns a value from the Model.

I want to fill a TextArea, edit it , and then return the edited value.

The below doesn't work.  I just get the original Model value back whereas I want the edited value of Comment

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", rows = 10 } })
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateComments", new { bookingID = Model.BookingID, newComment = Model.Comment }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "UpdateComments" }))
      {
         <div>
              <a href="#" class="btn  btn-default" onclick="document.getElementById('UpdateComments').submit();">Save</a> 
         </div>                       
      }
```

This is my action result.

```
    public ActionResult UpdateComments(int bookingID, string newComment)
    {
```

I have tracked all over the web but I don't understand what I should do.

Comment: try using textareafor instead of editorfor

Comment: also try to put your textAreafor inside of the form

Comment: Tried both of those and still getting back the original value of Model.Comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of your textarea isn't submitted to the server as part of the form collection because it's outside your form. Move it inside the form and you should find that it works.

You could also simplify things by replacing your anchor tag and its onclick handler with an input of type submit, which will submit the form by default when clicked.

Edit:

On further inspection, the route data that you are including with the form is causing the compile-time value of the model's `Comment` property to be posted back to the server as `newComment`.

Having moved the text area inside the form, the form collection will now also be including the user's entry as `Comment`, so you should change the action method's signature to:

```
public ActionResult UpdateComments(int bookingID, string Comment)
```

You can remove `newComment = Model.Comment` from the anonymous object that is passed as the second argument to the `BeginForm` method.

Comment: Tried that (put inside form) but still getting back the original value of Model.Comment.